# eclipselink repeats same query thousand of times then stackoverflow exception

Tags: eclipselink, stack-overflow, repeat

I have a jsf project that is already deployed on oracle application server many times before, it uses eclipse link 2.2.0, in a new recent installation the site crashes while loading data from DB, as it keeps executing same query thousand of times then it throws stackoverflow exception

If i connect to the same new installation from my local jdev the application start normally, so it seems server configuration issue and not coding issue.
code used to create object descriptor

```
public ClassDescriptor buildTLEntityPCDAODescriptor() {
    RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
    descriptor.setJavaClass(com.its.tabs.tpc.layers.dal.entity.toplink.TLEntityPCDAO.class);
    descriptor.addTableName("TPC_ENTITIES");
    descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");

    // Inheritance Properties.

    // Descriptor Properties.
    descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
    descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
    descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
    descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
    descriptor.setSequenceNumberFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.setSequenceNumberName("SEQ_ENTITIES");
    descriptor.setAlias("TLEntityPCDAO");

    // Cache Invalidation Policy
    TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy policy = new TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy(1);
    policy.setShouldUpdateReadTimeOnUpdate(false);
    descriptor.setCacheInvalidationPolicy(policy);

    // Query Manager.
    descriptor.getQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();

    DirectToFieldMapping descriptionMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    descriptionMapping.setAttributeName("description");
    descriptionMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.DESCRIPTION");
    descriptor.addMapping(descriptionMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping serviceProviderCodeMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    serviceProviderCodeMapping.setAttributeName("serviceProviderCode");
    serviceProviderCodeMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_CODE");
    descriptor.addMapping(serviceProviderCodeMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping entity_idMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    entity_idMapping.setAttributeName("entity_id");
    entity_idMapping.setNullValue(new Long(0));
    entity_idMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(entity_idMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping idMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    idMapping.setAttributeName("id");
    idMapping.readOnly();
    idMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(idMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping levelIdMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    levelIdMapping.setAttributeName("levelId");
    levelIdMapping.setNullValue(new Long(0)); //changed from -1 to 0
    levelIdMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.LEVEL_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(levelIdMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping lookupIdMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    lookupIdMapping.setAttributeName("lookupId");
    lookupIdMapping.setNullValue(new Long(0)); //changed from -1 to 0
    lookupIdMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.LOOKUP_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(lookupIdMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping levelDepthMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    levelDepthMapping.setAttributeName("levelDepth");
    levelDepthMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.LEVEL_DEPTH");
    descriptor.addMapping(levelDepthMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping entity_sequenceMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    entity_sequenceMapping.setAttributeName("entity_sequence");
    entity_sequenceMapping.setNullValue(new Long(0));
    entity_sequenceMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_SEQUENCE");
    descriptor.addMapping(entity_sequenceMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping entity_typeMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    entity_typeMapping.setAttributeName("entity_type");
    entity_typeMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_TYPE");
    descriptor.addMapping(entity_typeMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping nameMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    nameMapping.setAttributeName("name");
    nameMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.NAME");
    descriptor.addMapping(nameMapping);

    DirectToFieldMapping parent_entity_idMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
    parent_entity_idMapping.setAttributeName("parent_entity_id");
    parent_entity_idMapping.setNullValue(new Long(0)); //changed from -1 to 0
    parent_entity_idMapping.setFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.PARENT_ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(parent_entity_idMapping);

    AggregateObjectMapping auditFieldsMapping = new AggregateObjectMapping();
    auditFieldsMapping.setAttributeName("auditFields");
    auditFieldsMapping.setReferenceClass(com.its.tabs.architecture.dal.persistency.AuditFields.class);
    auditFieldsMapping.setIsNullAllowed(false);
    auditFieldsMapping.addFieldNameTranslation("TPC_ENTITIES.CREATED_BY", "createdBy->DIRECT");
    auditFieldsMapping.addFieldNameTranslation("TPC_ENTITIES.MODIFIED_BY", "modifiedBy->DIRECT");
    auditFieldsMapping.addFieldNameTranslation("TPC_ENTITIES.CREATED_DATE", "createdDate->DIRECT");
    auditFieldsMapping.addFieldNameTranslation("TPC_ENTITIES.MODIFIED_DATE", "modifiedDate->DIRECT");
    descriptor.addMapping(auditFieldsMapping);

    OneToManyMapping entitesMapping = new OneToManyMapping();
    entitesMapping.setAttributeName("entites");
    entitesMapping.setReferenceClass(com.its.tabs.tpc.layers.dal.entity.toplink.TLEntityPCDAO.class);
    entitesMapping.useTransparentCollection();
    entitesMapping.useCollectionClass(org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.class);
    entitesMapping.addTargetForeignKeyFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.PARENT_ENTITY_ID", "TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(entitesMapping);

    OneToManyMapping entityattributesMapping = new OneToManyMapping();
    entityattributesMapping.setAttributeName("entityattributes");
    entityattributesMapping.setReferenceClass(com.its.tabs.tpc.layers.dal.entityattributes.toplink.TLEntityAttributesDAO.class);
    entityattributesMapping.useTransparentCollection();
    entityattributesMapping.useCollectionClass(org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.class);
    entityattributesMapping.addTargetForeignKeyFieldName("TPC_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.ENTITY_ID", "TPC_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(entityattributesMapping);

    OneToOneMapping entityLevelIdMapping = new OneToOneMapping();
    entityLevelIdMapping.setAttributeName("levels");
    entityLevelIdMapping.setReferenceClass(TLLevelsDAO.class);
    entityLevelIdMapping.useProxyIndirection();
    entityLevelIdMapping.readOnly();
    entityLevelIdMapping.addForeignKeyFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.LEVEL_ID", "TPC_LEVELS.LEVEL_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(entityLevelIdMapping);

    OneToOneMapping entityLookupIdMapping = new OneToOneMapping();
    entityLookupIdMapping.setAttributeName("lookups");
    entityLookupIdMapping.setReferenceClass(TLLookupDAO.class);
    entityLookupIdMapping.useProxyIndirection();
    entityLookupIdMapping.readOnly();
    entityLookupIdMapping.addForeignKeyFieldName("TPC_ENTITIES.LOOKUP_ID", "TPC_LOOKUP.LOOKUP_ID");
    descriptor.addMapping(entityLookupIdMapping);

    return descriptor;
}
```

code used to read entities

```
        List<EntityPCEntity> entityList      = new ArrayList<EntityPCEntity>();            
        entityList = (List<EntityPCEntity>)this.getTABSEntityManagerFinder().getEclipseLinkAdapter().readMultipleDAOs(TLEntityPCDAO.class);

       return entityList;
```

exception

14/06/17 13:03:36 Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
14/06/17 13:03:36   at com.evermind.server.connector.ApplicationConnectionManager.getTransaction(ApplicationConnectionManager.java:1582)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at com.evermind.server.connector.ApplicationConnectionManager.getConnectionFromShareablePool(ApplicationConnectionManager.java:1652)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at com.evermind.server.connector.ApplicationConnectionManager.acquireConnectionContext(ApplicationConnectionManager.java:1497)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at com.evermind.server.connector.ApplicationConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ApplicationConnectionManager.java:1449)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at oracle.j2ee.connector.OracleConnectionManager.unprivileged_allocateConnection(OracleConnectionManager.java:238)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at oracle.j2ee.connector.OracleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(OracleConnectionManager.java:192)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at oracle.oc4j.sql.ManagedDataSource.getConnection(ManagedDataSource.java:197)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at oracle.oc4j.sql.ManagedDataSource.getConnection(ManagedDataSource.java:142)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at oracle.oc4j.sql.ManagedDataSource.getConnection(ManagedDataSource.java:127)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:291)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(DatasourceAccessor.java:565)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.reconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1434)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.incrementCallCount(DatasourceAccessor.java:305)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:570)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:526)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1729)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:667)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2603)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2574)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:444)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1080)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:808)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:412)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1126)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2842)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1521)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1503)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.checkAndRefreshInvalidObject(AbstractSession.java:1024)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:960)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:628)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:565)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:497)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:456)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:723)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:766)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:451)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1080)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:808)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:412)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1126)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2842)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1521)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1503)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.checkAndRefreshInvalidObject(AbstractSession.java:1024)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:960)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:628)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:565)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:497)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:456)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:723)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:766)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:451)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1080)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:808)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:412)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1126)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2842)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1521)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1503)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.checkAndRefreshInvalidObject(AbstractSession.java:1024)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:960)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:628)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:565)
14/06/17 13:03:36   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:497)

Comment: You're using a really weird way of reading the database.  Isn't it normal to use `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your invalidation policy:

```
TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy policy = new TimeToLiveCacheInvalidationPolicy(1);
policy.setShouldUpdateReadTimeOnUpdate(false);
descriptor.setCacheInvalidationPolicy(policy);
```

You've set it to be invalidated within a millisecond, likely before it can even be finished being read in.  While I can't see much more about your object model or the queries that are being executed, this is likely a very large contributor to your problem, as it means that any references to this object will almost always be invalidated and forced to query for it again.